# Lambda Functions in python 3.x

Tags: python, dictionary, filter, lambda

How we can exclude the negative numbers from a given list and taking the square of only positive numbers being filtered. This all should be done using

`a = map( ---- , array)`

In the dash above, we have to write lambda function.

Comment: You can't exclude numbers with `map`. You have to use `filter` or a list comprehension.

Comment: If you square all the numbers, then the negative ones will become positive. Is that what you want?

Comment: we have to exclude negative numbers first, thats the requirement of question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter positive numbers first and then apply the square:

```py
map(lambda x: x**2, filter(lambda i: i>0, l))
```

Although there are more effective ways to do this (*performance-wise*) with a list comprehension:

```py
[i**2 for i in l if i>0]
```

Comment: This was a question on remotebase test so we only need lambda to do that. So this is a correct answer

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
import numpy as np

array = np.arange(-5, 5, 1)
map(lambda x: x**2 if x > 0 else None, array)
```

Comment: There None values in result array. I want to exclude to in this lambda too

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).